# query unique database with condition followed SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Claim      |    Flag
--------------------
2657       |    5
2657       |    5
2657       |    5
2657       |    2
2659       |    5
2659       |    5
2659       |    5
```

I want to query records with condition is that the claim has Flag '5' and does not have Flag = '2' either.
For example, In this case: claim 2657 has Flag '5' but has Flag '2' as well. So We skip it.
Just query claim '2659'.

Please help me write query in SQl Server to meet this condition.

Comment: Would you please show us what you already tried?

Comment: can you post the output you want ??question is bit unclear

Comment: select claim,flag from table where flag <> 2

Comment: You should look into using "not exists" / "exists" in your SQL, that's probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a ***Relational Division with no Remainder (RDNR)*** problem. See this [**article**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) by Dwain Camps that provides many solution to this kind of problem.

[**SQL Fiddle #1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1769/1/0)

```
SELECT s.Claim
FROM SampleData s
WHERE s.Flag IN(5)
GROUP BY s.Claim
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.Flag) = 1
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT s.Flag) = (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT Flag) 
        FROM SampleData 
        WHERE Claim = s.Claim
    )
```

---

If you want to specify that the record shouldn't have a `Flag = 2`, this will do:

[**SQL Fiddle #2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1769/2/0)

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Claim
FROM SampleData s
WHERE
    s.Flag IN(5)
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM SampleData WHERE Claim = s.Claim AND Flag = 2
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use `GROUP BY` with conditional `HAVING` (similar to wewesthemenace approach 1) like this .

```
SELECT c.Claim
FROM Claims c
GROUP BY c.Claim
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.Flag = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN c.Flag = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfb4a/2)

Comment: I think this will be faster than my first solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

This could sort your issue

SELECT CLAIM
FROM claim 
GROUP BY CLAIM HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FLAG) = 1